# Why java.util.InputMismatchException is throwed in this code?

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int m = in.nextInt();
            String s = in.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int pos = in.nextInt();    // <- Line 14
                char c = (char)in.nextByte();
                s = s.substring(0, pos) + c + (pos + 1 < n ? s.substring(pos + 1) : "");
                System.out.println(f(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I input

`10 3
.b..bz....`

The program throws an exception immediately:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

I don't even have chance to input `pos` and `c`.

Could anybody tell me what is wrong in this snippet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Thats because the Scanner#nextInt method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextInt*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int pos = in.nextInt();
```

For the input of b which cannot be converted to an integer. That is why the exception is thrown.